# ActiveMQ messageId not working to stop duplication

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ for messaging and there is one requirement that if message is duplicate then it should handled by AMQ automatically. 
For that I generate unique message key and set to messageproccessor. 
following is code :

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(dataQueue, event, messagePostProccessor -> {

    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
    long ms = dt.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY) / 1000;
    String messageUniqueId = event.getResource() + event.getEntityId() + ms;
    System.out.println("messageUniqueId : " + messageUniqueId);
    messagePostProccessor.setJMSMessageID(messageUniqueId);
    messagePostProccessor.setJMSCorrelationID(messageUniqueId);
    return messagePostProccessor;
});
```

As it can be seen code generates unique id and then set it to messagepostproccessor.

Can somehelp me on this, is there any other configuration that I need do.

Comment: Your call to [`setJMSMessageID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSMessageID-java.lang.String-) won't ultimately have any impact because the JMS provider (i.e. the broker & client implementation you're using) assigns the ID to the message when it is sent. Notice that the JavaDoc says, "This method is for use by JMS providers only to set this field when a message is sent. This message cannot be used by clients to configure the message ID."

Comment: Also, invoking [`setJMSCorrelationID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationID-java.lang.String-) won't have any impact on duplicate detection as that is not what the correlation ID is used for.  Notice that the JavaDoc says, "A client can use the JMSCorrelationID header field to link one message with another. A typical use is to link a response message with its request message."

Comment: The JMS specification doesn't define duplicate detection so you'll have to use a provider-specific mechanism as outlined in Domenico's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consumer can receive duplicate messages mainly for two reasons: a producer sent the same message more times or a consumer receive the same message more times.

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis includes powerful automatic [duplicate message detection](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/duplicate-detection.html), filtering out messages sent by a producer more times.

To prevent a consumer from receiving the same message more times, an idempotent consumer must be implemented, ie Apache Camel provides an Idempotent consumer component that would work with any JMS provider, see: http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html